# KableExtra - collapse_rows alignment

Tags: r, knitr, r-markdown, kable, kableextra

I put the following code in my R Markdown document and it nicely collapses rows based on the structure of my data frame. As you can see there is an `align` argument that horizontally aligns the data. Is there a similar `align_vertical` argument that allows me to align vertically? In particular I'd like the "a" and "b" from the output below to be *vertically top-aligned*. Currently they are *vertically center-aligned*.

```
library(kableExtra)
library(knitr)

collapse_rows_dt <- data.frame(C1 = c(rep("a", 10), rep("b", 5)),
                 C2 = c(rep("c", 7), rep("d", 3), rep("c", 2), rep("d", 3)),
                 C3 = 1:15,
                 C4 = sample(c(0,1), 15, replace = TRUE))

kable(collapse_rows_dt, "html", align = "c") %>%
  kable_styling(full_width = F) %>%
  column_spec(1, bold = T) %>%
  collapse_rows(columns = 1:2)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you change the order of the commands (execute `column_spec` at last`) you can use`extra_css`to change the`vertical-align` property:

```
library(kableExtra)
library(knitr)

collapse_rows_dt <- data.frame(C1 = c(rep("a", 10), rep("b", 5)),
                               C2 = c(rep("c", 7), rep("d", 3), rep("c", 2), rep("d", 3)),
                               C3 = 1:15,
                               C4 = sample(c(0,1), 15, replace = TRUE))

kable(collapse_rows_dt, "html", align = "c") %>%
  kable_styling(full_width = F) %>%
  collapse_rows(columns = 1:2) %>%
  column_spec(1, bold = T, extra_css = 'vertical-align: top !important;')
```

[image]

Comment: Is there an error in your syntax? R spits this at me when I copy paste your reply directly into an Rmd chunk `Quitting from lines 63-72 (mark_output.Rmd) 
Error in column_spec(., 1, bold = T, extra_css = "vertical-align: top !important;") : 
  unused argument (extra_css = "vertical-align: top !important;")`

Comment: add that did the trick! Thank you. A final question if I may... Why are the `a` `b` and `d` properly aligned at the top, yet the `c` remains *center-aligned*. Strange, no?

Comment: Dang did'nt notice that. It is because of the HTML structure. Inside the first `<tr>` we have all 4 columns (`<td>` elements), so `bold=T` is applied correctly. In the second row we only have 2 columns (`<td>` elements) and hence the 2 is bold! Need to think about that...

Comment: I can't figure out a way to do that without using Javascript! :/

Comment: Most of my data frames only consist of one level of grouping (eg the `a` and the `b`) so it shouldn't even be an issue. Your answer gets me what I need and I appreciate it. I've noticed your name a bit on these forums and you do great work!

Comment: Oh boy, I'm blushing. Thx ;) One could probably add an issue on the corresponding github. If the value of  `extra_css` would be added to the `style` attribute at very last, it would work.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/166265/discussion-between-stackinator-and-martin-schmelzer).